# Moving rows in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I work with the MVC pattern and I've a JTable like this :

```
List<Enregistrement> desEnregistrements = dao.lireTousLesEnregistrements(1);
    
    ((VueAfficherCompteCIO)vue).getModeleJTableCIO().addColumn("Date Enregistrement");
    ((VueAfficherCompteCIO)vue).getModeleJTableCIO().addColumn("Libellé");
    ((VueAfficherCompteCIO)vue).getModeleJTableCIO().addColumn("Motif");
    ((VueAfficherCompteCIO)vue).getModeleJTableCIO().addColumn("Date facture");
    ((VueAfficherCompteCIO)vue).getModeleJTableCIO().addColumn("Mode de règlement");
    ((VueAfficherCompteCIO)vue).getModeleJTableCIO().addColumn("Montant");
    ((VueAfficherCompteCIO)vue).getModeleJTableCIO().addColumn("Solde");
    ((VueAfficherCompteCIO)vue).getModeleJTableCIO().addColumn("Etat");
    ((VueAfficherCompteCIO)vue).getModeleJTableCIO().addColumn("Modifier");
    ((VueAfficherCompteCIO)vue).getModeleJTableCIO().addColumn("RecDep");
    ((VueAfficherCompteCIO)vue).getModeleJTableCIO().addColumn("Anticipation");
    
    for (Enregistrement unEnregistrement : desEnregistrements) {
        ((VueAfficherCompteCIO)vue).getModeleJTableCIO().addRow(new String[]{unEnregistrement.getDate(), unEnregistrement.getIdLibelle(), unEnregistrement.getMotif(), unEnregistrement.getDateFacture(), unEnregistrement.getModeReglement(), unEnregistrement.getMontant(), unEnregistrement.getNouveauSolde(), unEnregistrement.getIdEtat(),unEnregistrement.getId(), unEnregistrement.getRecetteDepense(), unEnregistrement.getAnticipation()});   
    }
    
    aspectJtable();
```

I would like to use a drag and move rows with this JTable so I implements this code : [How do I drag and drop a row in a JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638807/how-do-i-drag-and-drop-a-row-in-a-jtable)

But I don't understand how i can implement the interface "Reorderable" to my TableModel.

When I run my project I can use the drag and move (I see the drag...) but there is no movement.

Next, I've this error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: vues.VueAfficherCompteCIO$1 cannot be cast to controleurs.Reorderable
at controleurs.TableRowTransferHandler.importData(TableRowTransferHandler.java:55)
at javax.swing.TransferHandler$DropHandler.drop(TransferHandler.java:1536)
at java.awt.dnd.DropTarget.drop(DropTarget.java:450)
at javax.swing.TransferHandler$SwingDropTarget.drop(TransferHandler.java:1274)
at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer.processDropMessage(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:537)
at sun.awt.X11.XDropTargetContextPeer.processDropMessage(XDropTargetContextPeer.java:184)
at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer$EventDispatcher.dispatchDropEvent(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:851)
at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer$EventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:775)
at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetEvent.dispatch(SunDropTargetEvent.java:48)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4716)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processDropTargetEvent(Container.java:4566)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4417)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

The 55 line is :

```
((Reorderable)table.getModel()).reorder(rowFrom, index);
```

Someone can help me, and explain how it's work ?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I drag and drop a row in a JTable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638807/how-do-i-drag-and-drop-a-row-in-a-jtable)

Comment: yes i write this in my question... I would like to know how to implement Reorderable first...

Comment: What **exactly** is your problem? I assume you know how to add `implements Reorderable` to your table model.

Comment: Should I change TableModel.java ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I correctly understand the code in the sample to implement the interface `Reorderable` you simply should get the row which is placed at the `fromIndex` and inserts at the `toIndex`.

Example:

```
public class ReorderableTableModel extends DefaultTableModel implements Reorderable {
  public void reorder(int from, int to) {
    Object o = getDataVector().remove(from);
    getDataVector().add(to, o);
    fireTableDataChanged();
  }
}
```

Do not forget to set the instanceo of this table model to your table

Comment: Thx, but where can I use this interface ? in the ((Reorderable)table.getModel()).reorder(rowFrom, index); ? This is not clear for me

Comment: Your table model must implement the interface Reorderable. I will update my answere with an example.

Comment: Oh ok !! I understand now. I do that but i've not extend with DefaultTableModel.... Sorry for that...

Comment: The code won't work correctly when you move rows down. See my answer for a fix.

Answer (score 6):

The question [How do I drag and drop a row in a JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638807/how-do-i-drag-and-drop-a-row-in-a-jtable) contains all the information you need.

When you create the `JTable`, you have to specify a table model. This model must implement the interface `Reorderable` (copy the code from the question above) so the `TransferHandler` will work. This isn't an official Swing API, it's just something that makes the `TransferHandler` reusable.

The new method must move the row at `fromIndex` to the new position `toIndex`. If you use an `ArrayList`:

```
 Object row = list.remove( fromIndex );
 if( fromIndex < toIndex ) { toIndex --; } // We now have one row less!
 list.add( toIndex, row );
```

Comment: Thx, my table model is in my View and declare like this :modeleJTableCIO = new DefaultTableModel(){
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
               return false;
            }
            
        };                                                                       How can I implements Reorderable so ?

Comment: @PerroinThibault: move the inline class into a new type/file. Create a new "Reorderable.java" and put the code for the interface in there. Make the new type implement the interface.