# JTable drag and drop

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to implement JTable drag and drop, I have been able to get it working for the most part based on the solution provided in this question ([How do I drag and drop a row in a JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638807/how-do-i-drag-and-drop-a-row-in-a-jtable)) and this question ([Moving rows in JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524657/moving-rows-in-jtable)) tweaked slightly to my needs.

The issue I am running into too is it works fine for the most part though using the TableModel like the one found here ([Moving rows in JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524657/moving-rows-in-jtable)), dragging in for example a three row JTable, dragging the first row to the second row works fine though dragging for example the first row to the bottom below the third row results in a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and the row disappears. The error occurs in the line: getDataVector().add(to, o);

The issue occurs with the following code from [Moving rows in JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524657/moving-rows-in-jtable):

```
public class ReorderableTableModel extends DefaultTableModel implements Reorderable {
    public void reorder(int from, int to) {
         Object o = getDataVector().remove(from);
         getDataVector().add(to, o);
         fireTableDataChanged();
    }
}
```

There seems to also be an answer by Aaron on this question as to why it may not be working: [Moving rows in JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524657/moving-rows-in-jtable) though I was unsure of how to implement Aaron's answer into my scenario.

Stacktrace is:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 > 1
    at java.util.Vector.insertElementAt(Vector.java:598)
    at java.util.Vector.add(Vector.java:814)
    at com.testproject.test.table.TableModel.reorder(TableModel.java:25)
    at com.testproject.test.table.TableRowTransferHandler.importData(TableRowTransferHandler.java:49)
    at javax.swing.TransferHandler$DropHandler.drop(TransferHandler.java:1544)
    at java.awt.dnd.DropTarget.drop(DropTarget.java:455)
    at javax.swing.TransferHandler$SwingDropTarget.drop(TransferHandler.java:1282)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer.processDropMessage(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:538)
    at sun.lwawt.macosx.CDropTargetContextPeer.processDropMessage(CDropTargetContextPeer.java:143)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer$EventDispatcher.dispatchDropEvent(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:852)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer$EventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:776)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetEvent.dispatch(SunDropTargetEvent.java:48)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4746)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processDropTargetEvent(Container.java:4599)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4461)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I have attempted to resolve this issue though I am unable to, what would be the best way to resolving this issue?

Comment: What is your stacktrace?

Comment: @YassinHajaj sorry for not including it, I have edited the question to include it. There is answer on a similar but not exact question here by Aaron as to why it may not be working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524657/moving-rows-in-jtable though I am unable to figure out how to implement Aaron's answer into my reorder method.

Comment: What if you try `get` instead of `remove` and then use `remove` ?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've removed an element from the `Vector` you should consider some of your `indexes` to become `index-=1`;

---

### Solution

```
public void reorder(int from, int to) {
     Object o = getDataVector().remove(from);
     getDataVector().add(from>to?to:to-1, o);
     fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

Check if the index of `from` is greater than `to`. If it is the case, than we know the index of `to` has not changed, if it is not, change it by removing one to the index.

Comment: @maldahleh My pleasure :)