# drag and drop rows from a single column (not whole row)

Tags: java, swing, jtable

based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4769575/145574) I have implemented a handy feature to drag and drop rows in a JTable to re-order them. The feature is attached to the whole table however, and I would like to attach it only to one column (displayed as an icon) so that the mouse events don't get affected in other columns.

The whole row is to be dragged/re-ordered, however I want to use a specialised icon as the 'handle' for dragging which would appear in the far left or far right column. I have seen this concept done before (not in java) but can't find a suitable example right now.

Currently, the drag handler is installed like this:

```
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
table.setDragEnabled(true);
table.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT_ROWS);
table.setTransferHandler(new ReorderRowTransferHandler(table));
```

Is there a way to attach the drag handler to a single column only?

EDIT: @Kleopatra's answer is good, however part of my problem is that my other columns contain comoponents such as buttons which due to the drag handler, no longer show their 'pressed' state. i'm hoping to find a solution which restricts the drag mouse handler so that it impacts the first column.

Comment: Alternatively, consider a combo editor to select the desired icon for a row.

Comment: So you want to move a single cell?

Comment: @MadProgrammer no i want to move the whole row, but not make the whole row active in terms of initiating the drag... so there would be an icon in the far left (or far right) column which would be the 'handle' for dragging.

Comment: still not entirely sure what your problem is, if my answer doesn't fit, please comment :-)

Comment: i'm fairly sure the tables automatic drag behaviour is going to be tied up in TableUI ... I might have to look into attaching a custom mouselistener to the table and initiating drag manually from there...

Answer (score 2):

To start dnd only if the mouse drag is initiated in the (f.i.) the first column of the table, implement the exportAsDrag method of the custom TransferHandler to return NONE elsewhere, something like:

```
@Override
public void exportAsDrag(JComponent comp, InputEvent e, int action) {
    if (e instanceof MouseEvent) {
        MouseEvent mouse = (MouseEvent) e;
        if (table.columnAtPoint(mouse.getPoint()) != 0) {
            action = NONE;
        }

    }
    super.exportAsDrag(comp, e, action);
}
```

Comment: +1, this "works" in that, only the specified column can initiate the drag.. however part of the reason i was looking for a solution is that other columns are behaving slightly differently now (button columns don't show their 'pressed' state) due to the drag handler. I am hoping i can find a way to only alter the behaviour of the single drag column... any ideas?

Comment: @pstanton no - actually I'm not really understanding the issue you describe ;-) Time for a SSCCE to see what you are doing and how the dragHandler interfers

Comment: that would be one big SSCCE! i'll see if i get time over the next couple of days. thanks for the help.

Comment: @pstanton _one big SSCCE_ - that's a contradiction in itself, one of the S stands for **small** :-) Strip it down to the barest essentials, typically a max of 50 - 100 lines are more than enough