# Java: How to drag JTable rows without usage of TransferHandler?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, drag-and-drop, jtable

In Java, `JTable` by default does not offer the functionality to drag `JTable` rows for reordering the table. Many of the answers I see online, suggest that you should use a custom `TransferHandler` implementation to achieve this behaviour. However, I find that that highly overcomplicates things and there needs to be an easier way to do so. Can anyone give suggestions on how to more efficiently drag & drop table rows for reordering the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve this behavior, you can use a combination of a `MouseListener` and a `MouseMotionListener`. `DefaultTableModel` provides functionality with which you can translate the `Point` of an event to the row in which the event occured. Using this functionality, we can effectively drag table rows around. The code sample below shows a basic implementation with which table rows are dragged in real-time. Please note that the `table` and `tableModel` properties are weakified on purpose: We do not want the `MouseHandler` to keep a strong reference to either the `table` or the `tableModel`.

```
public class MouseHandler implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    private Integer row = null;

    private final WeakReference<JTable> table;
    private final  WeakReference<DefaultTableModel> tableModel;

    public MouseHandler(JTable table, DefaultTableModel model) {
        this.table = new WeakReference<>(table);
        this.tableModel = new WeakReference<>(model);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {}

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
        JTable table;
        if((table = this.table.get()) == null) {
            return;
        }
        int viewRowIndex = table.rowAtPoint(event.getPoint());
        row = table.convertRowIndexToModel(viewRowIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
        row = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
        JTable table;
        DefaultTableModel tableModel;
        if((table = this.table.get()) == null || (tableModel = this.tableModel.get()) == null) {
            return;
        }

        int viewRowIndex = table.rowAtPoint(event.getPoint());
        int currentRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(viewRowIndex);

        if(row == null || currentRow == row) {
            return;
        }

        tableModel.moveRow(row, row, currentRow);
        row = currentRow;
        table.setRowSelectionInterval(viewRowIndex, viewRowIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {}

}
```

This in my eyes is a much cleaner and more friendly implementation than most of the suggestions out there that use `TransferHandler`.

**Update 22th september 2019 11.51 CEST**
As suggested by [@MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer), the original example has issues when dealing with filtered/sorted tables. The example has now been updated to also support those. When moving rows in a sorted table, the moved row will be inserted one index after the next visible row. This means that in the underlying model, the row may be moved more than one index at a time.

Important: When you want to ensure that your table remains filtered/sorted after moving the row, ensure that you called `setSortsOnUpdates(true)` on your table's sorter.

Comment: My only concern would be the fact that your not converting the view row index to the models row index - while I'd be concerned if your trying to do this on a table which is currently sorted, you could be do doing this on a table which is currently filtered, meaning the row indexes would be messed up.  Personally, I'd look towards a more abstract implementation - but since the OP's not provide any code, this is a good working demonstration

Comment: I know I only use Java 8 but how does this compile? I've searched the internet and can't find any new Java keywords for "self" or methods "unwrappedPerform()".

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'll take a look into that. This is tested only on a table that is unfiltered (as I have no use for filtered tables).

Comment: @camickr My bad, those are non-standard APIs. "self" is just a variable I use from inner classes to reference the surrounding parent class. "unwrappedPerform" is a function I use to check if a WeakReference is null and if not, if the weakly referenced property it is holding is null. If both are not null, then the lambda expression is executed on the weakly referenced object. I'll add the function to the code example.

Comment: @camickr As I just figured that the part using "self" and "unwrappedPerform" aren't relevant for the example, I removed it from the code above. However, if you are still interested in what the function is then you can take a look at https://github.com/WJJongkind/CowLite-Audioplayer/blob/rewrite_ui/CowLite%20Audioplayer/src/cap/util/SugarySyntax.java. As I mentioned, I use it to execute functions on weakly referenced objects :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have updated the code sample so that it also works with filtered tables. Thanks for the headsup!